# How to calculate anisotropic exchange J $J_{xy}, J_{xz}, J_{yz}, J_{yx}, ...$ using 4-state mapping and DFT?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, quantum-espresso, magnetism, algorithms

In [this review](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2013/dt/c2dt31662e/unauth), the authors present several schemes to calculate various quantities like single-ion anisotropy, DMI, and anisotropic exchange J using DFT. For instance, the DMI term in the y-direction $D_y$ is calculated as follows (extracted from the appendix):
[image: Source: https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2013/dt/c2dt31662e/unauth]

However, I could not find any literature on how to go about calculating the anisotropic J terms like $J_{xy}, J_{xz}, J_{yz}, J_{yx}, ...$. The review [1](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2013/dt/c2dt31662e/unauth) gives schema for calculating the diagonal elements $J_{xx}, J_{yy}, J_{zz}$, but not the others.

In [this paper](https://browse.arxiv.org/pdf/2002.10861.pdf), the authors give a scheme for $J_{xz}$ (below eq. 4). But that is basically the same as what [1](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2013/dt/c2dt31662e/unauth) gives for $D_y$. I don't think this should be the case.

So, would someone mind clarifying how I could go about calculating these non-diagonal anisotropic J.

---

**EDIT: I missed that [3](https://browse.arxiv.org/pdf/2002.10861.pdf) states that $D_y=J_{xz}=-J_{zx}$ if the off-diagonal terms are anti-symmetric. But this does not make sense to me. So, if the scheme in that paper is indeed correct, I don't understand why the anisotropic J are the same as DMI up to sign, at least for one block of the anisotropic J matrix...**

Comment: +1 welcome back TribalChief! Long time no see!